# How to concatenate an array into first position of n-d array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to add extra element to first position of n-d array in numpy.

Here is the code:

```
tmp_boxes3d = [None,6]

tmp_scores = [None]
```

Now I need to add tmp_scores element into first position of tmp_boxes3d.

For better understanding

```
boxes = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
scores = np.array([0,0])

boxes_scores = [[0,1,2,3,4],[0,5,6,7,8]]  # result
```

So I need to do for [None,6] shape.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `[None,3]` isn't a valid `numpy` shape.

Comment: The key to using `np.concatenate` is to understand dimensions.  Pay attention to the errors you get when using it.

Answer (score 3):

Try [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```py
boxes = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
scores = np.array([0,0])

np.concatenate((scores[:, np.newaxis],  boxes), axis=1)
```

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Or, `np.hstack`

```py
np.hstack((scores[:, np.newaxis],  boxes))
```